# Divisibility test for any arbitrary number n

Tags: number-systems

Does there exist any generalised method for 
devising a test of divisibility for any number.

I have found a method and am interested in doing further research in this area.

I want confirm whether any such method already exists.

Comment: Yes: divide the number in question by the possible divisor, and see whether there is any remainder.

Comment: @Darshan : I don't really understand your question - just do what Carl suggests.  Do you want a primality test?

Comment: @Darshan : testing whether one number is a multiple of one other number is extremely easy.  The problem requires "research" only if someone is doing something more general, such as testing whether any number in a large set is divisible by a number in some other set (?)

Answer (score 1):

There are many special divisibility rules for testing for divisibility by relatively small integers, and there is a [generalised divisibility rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Generalized_divisibility_rule) of much wider applicability.

Have you found anything which is a significant improvement on the rule given in the Wikipedia article?